# MySQLdump results in lots of commented lines, no real content

Tags: php, file, backup, mysql

I am trying to write a PHP program to automatically created backups of MySQL tables as sql files on the server:

```
$backup = "$path/$tablename.sql";
$table = "mydbname.mytablename";

exec(
  sprintf(
    '/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=%s --user=%s --password=%s %s --quick --lock-tables --add-drop-table > %s',
    $host,
    $user,
    $password,
    $table,
    $backup
  )
);
```

All that I get in the resulting .sql file is this:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.10
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: mydbname.mytablename
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.27

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

It seems fishy that the results list Database:mydbname.mytablename.

I don't know where to start looking. My host, in helping my set up the program initially, said I would need to deactivate safe_mode (was already done) and give access to the binary (I don't know what this means).

Since the host takes two days to reply every time I ask a question, I'd like to resolve this myself if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mysqldump command is like this :

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=HOST --user=USER --password=PASSWORD TABLE --quick --lock-tables --add-drop-table
```

Looking at [the manual of mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), I would say that it will think that TABLE is actually the name of your database *(quoting)* :

> There are three general ways to invoke
>   mysqldump:

```
shell> mysqldump [options] db_name [tables]
shell> mysqldump [options] --databases db_name1 [db_name2 db_name3...]
shell> mysqldump [options] --all-databases
```

Apparently, you have to put the name of the database before the name of the table you want to dump.

So, for instance, something like this might do the trick :

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --host=HOST --user=USER --password=PASSWORD DBNAME TABLE --quick --lock-tables --add-drop-table
```

Hope this helps !

EDIT : I actually made a quick test, using "databasename.tablename", like you did :

```
mysqldump --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --no-data DBNAME.TABLENAME
```

I'm getting the same kind of output you have... But I also have an error :

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1102: Incorrect database name 'DBNAME.TABLENAME' when selecting the database
```

Which, I'm guessing, is going to the error output, and not the standard output *(you are only redirecting that second one to your file)*

If I'm using :

```
mysqldump --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --no-data DBNAME TABLENAME
```

Everything works OK : no error, and I have the dump.

Comment: I added a space between the database name and the table name (instead of a period) and it worked fine. Thanks!